# Making Mongoose Aggregate Dynamic/Autonomous

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an app where users can start projects. A user can have multiple projects and each project has a status and also contains the email of the project owner.

**Project Schema:**

```
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

 url: {type: String},
 status: {type: String, default: 'incomplete' ,set: toLower},
 sector: {type: String, set: toLower},
 owner: {type: String, set: toLower}, //this contains the owners email
 title: {type: String, set: toLower},

 dateCreated: {type: Date, default: Date.now},

});
```

I am trying to send emails to users whose project status are **"incomplete"** but rather then sending each user an individual email for each project they own I want to be able to send a single email with a list of their **incomplete** projects.

**What I've done:**

```
Project.aggregate([{"$match": {"status": "incomplete", "owner": "jon.smith@email.com"}}], function(err, data) {});
```

The above returns me a all the `incomplete` projects by `jon.smith@email.com`. But the issue is I had to provide the users email.

**Please Note:** This function will not be run in response to a front-end users action but will be run by the server at specific time and date (Cron Job).

How can I make it more dynamic that the `owner` field is populated automatically? I can get a list of all users with projects but how do I populate the `aggregate` function with email address? Maybe `forOf loops`?

**FYI -
Users Schema:**

```
const userSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({

 email: String,
 password: String,
 fullName: String,
 usersProjects: [] // this contains the _id's of Project document created by the user

});
```

**Any advice will be appreciated. If you think my way is not good then please let me know how can I improve. (thats how I learn)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do as:

```
Project.aggregate([
 {"$match": {"status": "incomplete"},
 {"$group":{_id:{"$owner", projects:{$push: "$title"}}}}
], function(err, data) {});
```